# how do i insert radio button id value from a database in order to function well. i have tried this method but it seems like its not yet captured

Tags: php, html

this is  a php file for diplaying a radio button it is taken from a foeach loop.the database is working fine but the input attribute- id="" does not get assigned to the variable making it impossible for radio button to work

```
 <php>

 $output .='<input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="'$key['showtime_id']'" autocomplete="off">
        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2">'.$key['showtime_id'].'</label>';

?>
```

Comment: `id="'.$key['showtime_id'].'"` ...you forgot the concatenation operators. It should be giving you a syntax error - or it would if this was within a PHP block, but `<php>` doesn't start a PHP block - maybe you meant `<?php`?. P.S. This issue has nothing whatsoever to do with either AJAX or bootstrap. It's a simple PHP string manipulation and syntax issue, slightly related to HTML since that's what you're trying to generate. I retagged for you. Don't splurge tags into your question just because you use the tech elsewhere in your application, when it's not relevant to your specific question.

Comment: id="'.$key['showtime_id'].'" how should i rewrite it? ..

Comment: sorry  <php> is a typing error

Comment: `how should i rewrite it?`...what do you mean? That _is_ how you should rewrite it. Your version was missing the dots (`.`). Did you not have a syntax error showing?

Comment: id="'.$key['showtime_id'].'" i have done it like that  but it still not working

Comment: i think there is still a problem with my code let me check it out ..this is an action file in ajax

Comment: What does "not working" mean, exactly? What _specific_ problem are you having? Does `$output` get populated correctly? Does the AJAX not return correctly? or what else? It sounds like you need to do some basic debugging and narrow down your issue.

Comment: thanks i have found    $output .='  <input type="radio"name="checkTime" class="btn-check" id="'.$key['showtime_id'].'" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="'.$key['showtime_id'].'">'.$key['showtime_id'].'</label>';  i had not assigned the label for the radio button

Comment: for="" for the label was repeating i have assigne  a unique vale